# Undo redo for a huge object

Tags: javascript, node.js, design-patterns, data-structures, undo-redo

I have a requirement where the product needs to implement undo-redo functionality.

Currently I hold a huge Object which comes from a single mongo collection.

Pseudo structure:

```
{
  cart:{
    products:[
      {
        name: "Watch",
        quantity: 1,
        shippingDate: 123456782,
        text: "lorem ipsum....",
        prices:[
          {
            currency: "USD",
            price: 300
          },
          {
            currency: "GBP",
            price: 220
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    ...someMoreKeyValuePair
  }
}
```

Now the update can happen on any node, eg: product getting added/modified/removed, cart level data getting added/modified/removed.

And the structure is huge, now how do I maintain undo-redo actions on any change happening on the entire structure.

What data-structure or design pattern should I read to get a better approach on solving this.

Update:

undo-redo needs to be persisted in the DB. And the language I am using is the Javascript-NodeJS

Comment: Which language are you using? JavaScript? And this undo/redo operation, should that be persisted in the db, or is it only needed for in-memory objects, on the client?

Comment: Yes, I am using JS and it needs to be persisted in the DB. I ll update the question as well

Comment: You would need to keep a log of changes. So the client requests that your server application (nodejs) deals with should be translated into db actions that both log the change (in like an undo-log) and perform it, in one transaction. Then implement logic to clear the undo-log when appropriate, to pop an action from that log and perform the reverse action, ...etc.

Comment: Is it more like maintaining a log/set of actions for eg: `CHANGE_PRODUCT_NAME` becomes action and it will hold new name? And I keep building an array of these changes.

Comment: More generic, like `("update", "cart.products.0.name", newvalue, oldvalue)`, and `("delete", "cart.products.0", oldvalue-JSON)`, ...etc. You would have "update", "delete" and "insert" as actions, second argument would be a path into your object, other arguments would be JSON value(s).

Comment: that more makes sense, thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to keep a log of changes. So the client requests that your server application (nodejs) deals with should be translated into db actions that *both*
log the change (in like an undo-log) and perform it, in one transaction.

Then implement logic to clear the undo-log when appropriate, to pop an action from that log and perform the reverse action, ...etc.

A record in such an undo log would have 3 to 4 elements:

1. an action: "update", "insert", or "delete". That latter two are mostly intended to represent array manipulation.
2. a path to identify where in the object the change should be applied. This path would be an array of properties, which could for instance be encoded as a dot-separated string.
3. the old value at that location (in case of "update" or "delete"), JSON encoded.
4. the new value at that location (in case of "update" or "insert"), JSON encoded.

Examples of such records:

- `("update", "cart.products.0.name", '"Watch"', '"Watching"')`
- `("delete", "cart.products.prices.1", '{"currency":"GBP","price":220}', null)`: this represents an action where the old value is deleted from index 1 of the `prices` array. The gap is filled by shifting array values, much like a `splice(index, 1)` operation in JavaScript.
- `("insert", "cart.products.prices.0", null, '{"currency":"EUR","price":270}')`: this represents an action where the new value is inserted at index 0 in the `prices` array. If that index has already a value, it is shifted to the right, like a `splice(index, 0, newvalue)` operation in JavaScript.

The `null` values just indicate that this parameter is not relevant for that specific action.

The above example log would accumulate to the following data, starting from the example data you have given:

```
{
  cart:{
    products:[
      {
        name: "Watching",
        quantity: 1,
        shippingDate: 123456782,
        text: "lorem ipsum....",
        prices:[
          {
            currency: "EUR",
            price: 270
          },
          {
            currency: "USD",
            price: 300
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Such a log has everything to undo an action: in case data was wiped out ("update", "delete"), you can recover the wiped out data from the third parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [deep-diff](https://github.com/flitbit/diff), for instance.

> deep-diff is a javascript/node.js module providing utility functions
>   for determining the structural differences between objects and
>   includes some utilities for applying differences across objects.

So you could create differences between versions, and store them in your database:

```js
const change = diff(oldValue, newValue);
```

To apply a diff:

```js
applyChange(target, source, change);
```

[jsondiffpatch](https://github.com/benjamine/jsondiffpatch) is another option. If you use Mongoose, you can implement a plugin for managing changes, or use an existing one: [mongoose-diff-history](https://github.com/mimani/mongoose-diff-history)